# Error: Could not find a suitable provider for route53_a_record

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to setup a DNS Route53 record using puppet facts on an instance. I'm trying to use puppetlabs' aws module. I set it up as per their instructions, gems are installed, puppetserver restart (just to be sure). Instance has IAM role setup so it has access to Route53.

I'm using the latest puppet version 4.5.0 on CentOS 7.

This is how I setup the record:

```
    route53_a_record { "${::fqdn}.":
      ensure => 'present',
      ttl    => '3000',
      values => [ "${::ipaddress}" ],
      zone   => 'example.com.',
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
    Error: Could not find a suitable provider for route53_a_record
```

The `puppet describe route53_a_record` shows under providers only 'v2'.

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Comment: This typically occurs when Puppet is unable to find support for the provider in your system env/path. That would be very hit or miss to troubleshoot for you. By the way, the provider itself is https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-aws/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/route53_record.rb.

Comment: Thank you, this has taken me on to a new debugging path. When running the puppet agent in debug/verbose mode, I get this error: Debug: Failed to load library 'aws-sdk-core' for feature 'aws'
Debug: Puppet::Type::Route53_a_record::ProviderV2: feature aws is missing. So on to trying to fix that.

Comment: You mention `puppetserver` in your question. If you are in fact using the clojure-based puppetserver, did you also install the gem dependencies with `/opt/puppet/bin/puppetserver gem install aws-sdk-core retries` or similar?

Comment: Yeah I installed all dependencies as per puppetlabs' instructions. I used the command you mentioned as well. I managed to fix it in the meantime. Apparently Puppet installs gems to one path and it looks for them in another... I used the gem command from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin and it magically worked...